# Changing the color of toolbar OnsenUi

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm using OnsenUi framework for my webapp. and i need to know Is there any way to change the colour of toolbar based on the colour of the page. In other words, like Android 5 toolbar color effect.

If it possible, can you share me a snippet on how to do it?

If it's not, can you tell me where to change the color code manually, so that i can mimic that effect. What i found was, i can change the color of the toolbar in `.navigation-bar` background color, but it makes the toolbar to display only one color in every page. Can anybody tell me where to modify to get different color for different pages?

**Update #1**

i tried a simple method

```
<ons-toolbar style="background-color:#B1797A;>
```

but this breaks my navigation !!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: There is a "transparent" modifier for `ons-toolbar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `document.ready` handler, get the background-color of the `body` element and pass it to your toolbar, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bgColor = $('body').css("background-color");
    $('.navigation-bar').css("background-color", bgColor);
});
```

[**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/as0Le6ee/1/)

---

You can also see it happen when clicking on a button, in this demo:

[JsFiddle demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/as0Le6ee/)

Comment: Thanks @urbz, I used this in my OnsenUi webapp, it did set the toolbar color but it doesn't change while navigating to other pages.

Comment: You need to implement this script on every page, by referencing to your own `.js` file. So when the user is navigating to another page, you'll have that script ready, loaded and executed when the page is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

1. Go to the directory `/lib/onsenui/css` from the root of your project
2. Open `onsen-css-components.css`
3. Search for the class `.toolbar--material`
4. Modify the `background-color` property of the class to a color of your choice

This method worked for me.